# Tabula not extracting every row of data in a pdf

Tags: python, pandas, tabula

I've currently got an issue that i'm struggling a bit with. I'm trying to extract every row from a pdf using the tabula library. The issue i'm having is that generally the script is correctly extracting the data but for some reason it's not extracting every row:

```
Number of pages read: 20
Processing page 1 with 25 rows
Processing page 2 with 18 rows
Processing page 3 with 24 rows
Processing page 4 with 22 rows
Processing page 5 with 18 rows
Processing page 6 with 4 rows
Processing page 7 with 20 rows
Processing page 8 with 13 rows
Processing page 9 with 3 rows
Processing page 10 with 7 rows
Processing page 11 with 17 rows
Processing page 12 with 23 rows
Processing page 13 with 23 rows
Processing page 14 with 29 rows
Processing page 15 with 20 rows
Processing page 16 with 17 rows
Processing page 17 with 22 rows
Processing page 18 with 25 rows
Processing page 19 with 21 rows
Processing page 20 with 6 rows
Total rows after cleaning: 246
```

So pages 6,9,10 and 20 are not being fully extracted. The pdf itself is best described as having tables that don't have any lines or borders so using pdfplumber was a bit tricky when just using the vertical and horizontal strategy of text hence going down the route i did.

The script that i have written is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula
import getpass
from tabula import read_pdf

username = getpass.getuser()

# Fetch the PDF link
url = "https://dac.gouvernement.lu/fr/administration/departements/navigabilite/immatriculation-aeronefs/releve-immatriculations.html"
response = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
pdf_link = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/article/div/div/p[5]/a/@href')[0]

# If the link is relative, convert it to an absolute URL
if not pdf_link.startswith("http"):
    base_url = "https://dac.gouvernement.lu"
    pdf_link = f"{base_url}{pdf_link}"

# Download the PDF
response = requests.get(pdf_link)
pdf_path = f"C:/Users/{username}/Downloads/latest_pdf.pdf"

# Save the downloaded PDF
with open(pdf_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

# Read tables into a list of DataFrames, without headers
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all', pandas_options={'header': None})

print(f"Number of pages read: {len(dfs)}")

# Create an empty list to store cleaned rows
cleaned_rows = []

# Loop through each DataFrame in the list
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print(f"Processing page {i+1} with {len(df)} rows")
    
    current_row = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.notna(row[0]) and str(row[0]).startswith("LX-"):
            if current_row:
                cleaned_rows.append(current_row)
            current_row = list(row)
        else:
            for idx, element in enumerate(row):
                if pd.notna(element):
                    current_row[idx] = str(current_row[idx]) + " " + str(element) if pd.notna(current_row[idx]) else element

    if current_row:
        cleaned_rows.append(current_row)

print(f"Total rows after cleaning: {len(cleaned_rows)}")

# Convert the list of cleaned rows into a DataFrame
cleaned_df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_rows)

# Assign column names
cleaned_df.columns = ['Registration_Mark', 'Manufacturer', 'Aircraft_type', 'MSN', 'Registered_Owner', 'Registered_Operator']

cleaned_df['published_date'] = datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
cleaned_df['index'] = cleaned_df.index
```

I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction in how i can improve the accuracy and get the script to extract everything